# Server returns 403 error after submitting a form?

Tags: python, django, error-handling, web-hosting

So I just recently bought some web hosting and I'm trying to get my site setup and when I try submitting the form I get a "`Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`" And then it emails me the details on what went wrong and it says "`ViewDoesNotExist: Could not import users.views. Error was: No module named users.views`" when I clearly have a folder named users with a Python file named views inside of it. Is there some reason that it wouldn't be recognizing the folder?

Comment: Well, it's odd to get a CSRF error when it's really a server error? Make sure the folder has an `__init__.py` so that python can find it, and make sure `users` is a folder on your python path. It's generally recommended to just add your project parent folder to the path and do absolute imports like `myproject.users.views`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard the 403 error; If you have a form you need to provide a CSRF token too:

```
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/